# What do goroutines, Ruby Fibers, etc. look like to the OS/Kernel?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, operating-systems, go

In process concurrency and thread concurrency it's quite obvious how the kernel sees these as they map directly to real things that the kernel manages. When it comes to Golang goroutines and Ruby Fibers (these are similar things right?) I'm clueless as to how these are managed. Are they managed by the respective languages implementation/Virtual Machine(I know Go doesn't have a VM) or are they mapped to something that the kernel is better at handling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on the implementation. YARV implements Fibers itself, JRuby implements them as Java Threads, except on JVMs which have the proprietary experimental Coroutine extension (which is not part of the JVM Specification) where it implements them as JVM Coroutines.

It's the same as Threads, really. MRI implements Threads itself, YARV implements them as POSIX/Windows Threads, JRuby implements them as JVM Threads, IronRuby implements them as CLI Threads. Rubinius originally implemented them itself and later switched to implementing them as POSIX/Windows Threads.

The BEAM Erlang VM implements Processes itself. The Erjang Erlang VM implements them as Kilim Actors.

In other words: what Ruby Fibers etc. look like to the Kernel depends on what the author of the particular implementation wants them to look like to the Kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I suspected but wasn't sure. I've always liked the simplicity of implementing something to POSIX/UNIX standards more so than implementation specific.

Comment: Unfortunately, POSIX Threads are *really* expensive. You cannot have more than some 10000s of them. BEAM, OTOH, can handle tens of millions of Processes just fine, even though Processes are actually conceptually *more* expensive than Threads. (Threads only have their own Instruction Pointer, Processes have their own Memory as well.)

Comment: To answer the question about Go: Go keeps a list of goroutines to run for each thread (defaults to 1 thread, but you can ask for more). It can move excess goroutines to other threads when needed. Within each thread, it uses co-operative multitasking to switch between goroutines.